# Apache RewriteEngine, redirect sub-directory to another script

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I've been trying to achieve this since about 1.5 hours now. I want to have the following transformations when requesting sites on my website:

```
homepage.com/                           => index.php
homepage.com/archive                    => index.php?archive
homepage.com/archive/site-01            => index.php?archive/site-01
homepage.com/files/css/main.css         => requestfile.php?css/main.css
```

The first three transformations can be done by using the following:

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteRule     ^/?$                    index.php
RewriteRule     ^/?(.*)$                index.php?$1
```

However, I'm stuck at the point where all requests to the `files` subdirectory should be redirected to `requestfile.php`. This is one of the tries I've done:

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteRule     ^/?$                    index.php
RewriteRule     ^/?files/(.+)$          requestfile.php?$1
RewriteRule     ^/?(.*)$                index.php?$1
```

But that does not work. I've also tried to put `[L]` after the third line, but that didn't help as I'm using this configuration in `.htaccess` and sub-requests will transform that URL again, etc. I fuzzed with the `RewriteCond` command but I couldn't get it to work.

**How needs the configuration to look like to achieve what I desire?**

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteRule     ^/?$                    index.php
RewriteRule     ^/files/?(.*)$          /requestfile.php?$1

RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}          !^/files/$
RewriteRule     ^/?(.*)$                index.php?$1
```

Comment: That doesn't change the problem. I wouldn't even need to test it (Anyway, I did!). The problem is that after the line you quoted the URL is rewritten once again to be `index.php?requestfile.php`.

Comment: sry about that, went a little too fast. updated answer

Comment: hm, still don't get what this will change no (replacing `+` with `*` and adding `/` in fron of `requestfile.php$1`). This still does not prevent *mod_rewrite* to rewrite the URL rewritten by this rule once again with the `^/?(.*)$` rule.

Comment: Hm, seeing your recent edit, I'm going to try that one. I already tried to use `!` in front of a regular expression, but that didn't seem to work.. Anyway, gonna tell'ya in a minute, and thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Ok, that regular expression in the condition does work. But I need the `REQUEST_URI` not to match `/requestfile\.php` so that would be `RewriteCond ... !/requestfile\.php`. I'm going to take a look into the rewrite-log why it doesn't work this way.

Comment: It works. :) But quite a lot of to do when I need to do this for multiple subdirectories. I needed to add two conditions. They both match `REQUEST_URI` against the patterns `!/requestfile\.php` and `!/files` accordingly (I actually have a `RewriteBase` so I did not add `^` at the beginning of the regex). Isn't there a way to just stop a redirection after a rule has been applied? I mean, like the `[L]` flag, but that it really stops rewriting!? Thanks!